# Find the least sigma algebra that induces a real random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Consider $\Omega=\{1, 2, 3, 4 \}$. I want to find the least $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$, call her $\mathcal{F}$, so that $X(w)=w+1$ is a real random variable.

We want that, for any $A \in \mathcal{B}$ is satisfied that $X^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$, we can take

$$X^{-1}((-\infty, x])= \{w \in \Omega: X(w) \in (-\infty, x] \}= \{w \in \Omega: w+1 \in (-\infty, x] \}$$

Perhaps we could think about, $\mathcal{F}= \mathcal{P}$, but I don't see it so clear, for how could this be deduced from the set described above? perhaps by rewriting it himself?

Comment: What is $\mathcal P$ here again?

Comment: the set of all subsets of \mathcal{F}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can argue as follows:

- $X^{-1}((-\infty, 2]) = \{1\}$
  so $\{1\} \in \mathcal{F}$
- $X^{-1}((-\infty, 3]) = \{1, 2\}$ so $\{1, 2\} \in \mathcal{F}$ and also $\{2\} = \{1,2\}\setminus \{1\} \in \mathcal{F}$

Continuing this way you can show that all singletons belong to $\mathcal{F}$ so $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.